org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException while adding a baseline profile module
I have added a baseline profile module to my android project following the instructions on the android developers official documentation here. I am getting an org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException here.
The wizard in Android Studio adds the following lines to project level build.gradle file
plugins{
    id 'com.android.test' version '8.4.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.22' apply false
    id 'androidx.baselineprofile' version '1.2.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.4.0' apply false
}

When I try to gradle sync I am getting the following error
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.test', version: '8.4.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.test:com.android.test.gradle.plugin:8.4.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository <98 internal lines>
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.doExecute(ProjectImportAction.java:117)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:91)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:39)<84 internal lines>

How can I resolve this issue?

Same problem. @Mohit, were you able to fix it?

Check the accepted answer on this post @theapache64

So I finally found a solution. For some reason, gradle could not pick up  the plugin from the repositories mentioned in buildscript inside my project level build.gradle. The solution was to add all of my plugin repositories to the top of settings.gradle file.
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

After adding the repositories under pluginManagement my project was finally able to sync and the plugins were imported.

To avoid declaring repositories in settings.gradle.kts, as shown in the answer, you can add plugin classpath to the buildscript dependencies.
1. Add library to the libs.versions.toml:
[libraries]
baselineprofile-plugin = { module = "androidx.baselineprofile:androidx.baselineprofile.gradle.plugin", version.ref = "baselineprofile" }

2. Add classpath to dependencies in root build.gradle.kts:
dependencies {
    classpath(libs.baselineprofile.plugin)

3. Then add plugin with id to your modules:
plugins {
    id("androidx.baselineprofile")    

